# From SFO to San Jose with lots of luggage

Tags: luggage, airport-transfer, taxis, sfo, san-jose-california

We are two travellers, moving from San Franscisco airport to San Jose with 6 big bags. How would you recommend doing that?

I think we would need a taxi that the size of a [Volkswagen Transporter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen_Transporter):
[image]
Are there such taxis available at airport or should I consider some other means of travelling?

Comment: Just to make sure we get the tagging right: are you going to the city of San Jose or to San Jose airport (SJC)?

Comment: My flight arrives in San Francisco airport and I'm heading to a hotel in San Jose.

Comment: Right, I removed the irrelevant [sjc] tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a shuttle service (there are several, look them up [here](http://www.flysfo.com/web/page/tofrom/transp-serv/dtd/)), but you'll have to pay more for excessive baggage. For two with such a baggage it may be over $100.

It would probably be cheaper to just rent a car for a day. You can drive it from SFO to San Jose, and then return it at SJC airport (which is very close to the San Jose downtown). Your hotel will probably have a shuttle service to SJC, and if not - it will be $2.5 lightrail ticket from SJC back to the downtown.

Comment: Thanks, I reserved a private van from the link you provided. My choice of hotel changed from San Jose to Sunnyvale. The price for van to Sunnyvale was $79.

Answer (score 3):

If your hotel is in downtown, you could try BART to Millbrae and transfer to Caltrain. It is cheaper, and many (but not all) Caltrain train sets have a luggage rack in the middle car. It will be up to you to decide if you can handle getting all the bags onto the train

I second the idea of a one-way car rental rather than a taxi. Have one person take AirTrain to get the car while the second stays with all the luggage. The first person can easily drive back into the terminal to pick up everything.  Have the second person wait up at the departures level where it is easier to maneuver most of the time.

Comment: Caltrain to downtown SJ is an additional ride (bus or lightrail), wouldn't do it with so much luggage. If you do want to take that road - check with the hotel, maybe they can have their shuttle pick you up from the Caltrain station, it would make it easier.